# How to monitor mongrel server running ROR application on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crash, monitoring, mongrel

I have a Ruby on rails application that freezes over time. The rails logs are clean and donotshow anything. I suspect it freezes without any activity. 
Is there a way i can monitor and profile the mongrel server for leaks and errors? 
If yes how do i go about doing it.

There are tools like 'bleak_house' which work only for unix.

Thanks
Shaunak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there are no tools to monitor mongrel on windows